# MySQL Inner Join Against an Inner Join?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables "Employees", "EmployeeLeaveDays" and "EmployeeLeaves".

I'm looking to create a view that displays the date of the leave and the employee name. So in order for my calendar to work I have split everyones leave into individual days(EmployeeLeaveDays) which has an FK that links each day back to (EmployeeLeaves) which has other details around the leave, in EmployeeLeaves I have a column "employee" which is an FK back to employees which contains the name.

So In my view I want to return the name as you can see is 2 tables away, I've wrote this MySQL query but it doesn't work (returns no data), I'm wondering if there is anyway to do what I need to do?

```
SELECT
EmployeeLeaveDays.id,
EmployeeLeaveDays.employee_leave,
EmployeeLeaveDays.leave_date,
EmployeeLeaveDays.leave_type
FROM EmployeeLeaveDays
INNER JOIN EmployeeLeaves
ON EmployeeLeaveDays.employee_leave=EmployeeLeaves.employee
INNER JOIN Employees
ON EmployeeLeaves.employee=Employees.employee_id;
```

Hopefully from that you're able to see what I'm trying to achieve, how ever I've attached some screenshots of the table structure.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Thanks

Comment: What means `it doesn't work`?

Comment: And no pictures, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it just returns no data the columns are blank.

Comment: I have this query now that returns the employee ID, but I also want to return the name of that employee from the employees table, how would I join on to another join?
`SELECT
EmployeeLeaveDays.id,
EmployeeLeaveDays.employee_leave,
EmployeeLeaveDays.leave_date,
EmployeeLeaveDays.leave_type,
EmployeeLeaves.employee
FROM EmployeeLeaveDays
JOIN EmployeeLeaves ON EmployeeLeaveDays.employee_leave = EmployeeLeaves.id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking I got there in the end. Here's the final query.

```
SELECT
EmployeeLeaveDays.id,
EmployeeLeaveDays.employee_leave,
EmployeeLeaveDays.leave_date,
EmployeeLeaveDays.leave_type,
EmployeeLeaves.employee,
Employees.employee_id,
Employees.first_name,
Employees.last_name
FROM EmployeeLeaveDays
LEFT JOIN EmployeeLeaves ON EmployeeLeaveDays.employee_leave = EmployeeLeaves.id
LEFT JOIN Employees ON EmployeeLeaves.employee = Employees.id;
```